# Use variable to denote column letter in range

Tags: excel, vba, range

Snippet of the code:
I make the value in A equal to the value in B.

```
Set A = Workbooks("SwbA").Worksheets("SwsA").Range("A1:A10")
Set B = Workbooks("twbB").Worksheets("twsB").Range("G1:G10")
A.value = B.value
```

I want to declare a variable such as

```
Dim col AS STRING
col = "A"
```

So I can do something to this effect -

```
Set A = Workbooks("SwbA").Worksheets("SwsA").Range(col&1:col10)
```

[image]

Please take note, I don't want to do this -

```
col = "A1:A10" '--> this works, for other reasons I want to manipulate Column letter only
```

Comment: I don't want to add as a full answer as I know this must be a duplicate question.  Declare your columns using numbers (col A=1, B=2, etc).  An unqualified reference to columns `A:J` would then be:  `Debug.Print Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 10)).EntireColumn.Address`.  Good practice says to qualify both `Range` and `Cells` with the workbook & worksheet name which can be done within a `With....End With` block.

Comment: Another way would be to take the first column, calculate how many extra columns you need and resize the range `Debug.Print Columns(1).Resize(, 10).Address`.

Comment: You could use `Set B = Workbooks("SwbB").Worksheets("SwsB").Range(A.Offset(ColumnOffset:=6).Address)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I do not have the expertise to employ your suggestions. I am learning from this.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your image but you can do

```
 Dim Col As String
 Col = "A"
 Dim r As Range
 Set r = Range(Col & "1:" & Col & "10")
```

Comment: HD, i added line for missing image. I followed you suggestion - Set A = Workbooks("SwbA").Worksheets("SwsA").Range(col&"1:"&col"10"). It copy pastes to ALL columns, not limiting to col: A. But to the correct rows.

Comment: You're missing an &  Should be Set A = Workbooks("SwbA").Worksheets("SwsA").Range(col & "1:" & col & "10")

Comment: HD, Typo error in my post. My actual code is as you stated - Workbooks("SwbA").Worksheets("SwsA").Range(col & "1:" & col & "10") . This copy paste to all columns for the same rows.

Answer (score 0):

## Column Issue

When you declare a column as variant you can use either the **Letter** or **Number**. The `Cells` property is then appropriate to use.

### Number of Rows

```
Sub NumberOfRows()

  Const cW1 As String = "twbB"  ' Source Sheet or Book
  Const cW2 As String = "SwbA"  ' Target Sheet or Book

  Const cCol1 As Variant = "G"  ' Source Column Letter/Number
  Const cCol2 As Variant = "A"  ' Target Column Letter/Number
  Const cFirst As Long = 1      ' First Row
  Const cLast As Long = 10      ' Number of Rows

  Dim rngB As Range             ' Source Range
  Dim rngA As Range             ' Target Range

  Set rngB = Workbooks(cW1).Worksheets(cW1).Cells(cFirst, cCol1).Resize(cLast)
  Set rngA = Workbooks(cW2).Worksheets(cW2).Cells(cFirst, cCol2).Resize(cLast)

  rngA.Value = rngB.Value

End Sub
```

### Last Row

```
Sub LastRow()

  Const cW1 As String = "twbB"  ' Source Sheet or Book
  Const cW2 As String = "SwbA"  ' Target Sheet or Book

  Const cCol1 As Variant = "G"  ' Source Column Letter/Number
  Const cCol2 As Variant = "A"  ' Target Column Letter/Number
  Const cFirst As Long = 1      ' First Row
  Const cLast As Long = 10      ' Last Row

  Dim rngB As Range             ' Source Range
  Dim rngA As Range             ' Target Range

  Set rngB = Workbooks(cW1).Worksheets(cW1).Range(Cells(cFirst, cCol1), Cells(cFirst, cCol1))
  Set rngA = Workbooks(cW2).Worksheets(cW2).Range(Cells(cFirst, cCol2), Cells(cFirst, cCol2))

  rngA.Value = rngB.Value

End Sub
```